# How to call parent window function on close of child window in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

```
//Parent page javascript

function DoABC()
{
    //my logic goes here
}

function btnClick() //This function gets fired on the click event of a button which will open a child window now
{
    window.open("childpage.html", "_blank", "height=400, width=550, status=yes, toolbar=no, menubar=no, location=no, addressbar=no"); 
}
```

Now when I close this child form, after it gets closed, I want to call DoABC function.

I tried using window.onbeforeunload event of child window, but it did not work for me.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {

    event = event || window.event;

    var confirmClose = 'Are you sure?';

    // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
    if (event) {
       event.returnValue = "Are you sure";
    }

    // For Safari
    return confirmClose;

}
```

What could be the solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call window.onbeforeunload, you are referring to your current window object.  I would think this would work:

```
var newWin = window.open(....);

newWin.onbeforeonload = function () {....}
```

I haven't tried, but I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: newWin.onbeforeonload = function () {alert("hello");} is not working.