# How to use window.opener for using the functions from .js included in the parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

For exemple, in the parent page

```
<script src="js/test.js"></script>
```

and then we use window.open to open page 2, so in page 2, how do we use window.opener for calling functions in the test.js?

Comment: `window.opener.whateverfunction()`?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591050/javascript-window-opener-call-parent-function

Comment: @putvande I used  'try{
        if(parent.window.opener != null && !parent.window.opener.closed)
        {
          parent.window.opener.testCall();
        }

    }catch(e){ alert(e.description);' But get a undefined error. It maybe works only for the functions defined directely in the parent page not js/test.js ???

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle and reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`window.opener.functionOnParentPage();`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
window.opener.functionName()
```