# Window.opener in Microsoft Edge undefined when running at localhost

Tags: javascript, popupwindow, microsoft-edge

I'm using Microsoft Edge in localhost for development.

Website is accessed via `http://localhost`

I open a popup and want it to post a message to the opener via `window.opener.postMessage`

My code works with Chrome, and Safari, and even Microsoft Edge when the website is on staging or production.

But when I run in in local mode, the `window.opener` is undefined.

Comment: When you say `local mode` I assume you mean `file:///` instead of `http://localhost` - possible duplicate of [JavaScript window.opener call parent function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591050/javascript-window-opener-call-parent-function)

Comment: No as I said, I'm running it through `localhost`, with the `http://`

Comment: Then this is probably applicable: `It is also not supported in IE if the opener is in a different security zone.` from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener

Comment: As I said, the code works well when ran in production, even ran with Edge, and the targetOrigin the message listener is set to `'*'` to be usable with a desktop app built with Electron. Both popup and main window are in `http://localhost:9000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORS on localhost is tricky so try to create a domain name you like to your hosts file (%windir%\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts) - if you're in a Windows-based platform and map those back to 127.0.0.1.

You probably already know how to change the hosts file but just in case:

http://support.hostgator.com/articles/general-help/technical/how-do-i-change-my-hosts-file

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Edge runs in network isolation and does not currently support localhost testing. Run this in an elevated command prompt to enable loopback support:

```
CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n=Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

In a future update, you’ll be able to enable localhost loopback support using `about:flags`.

More info: http://dev.modern.ie/platform/faq/how-can-i-debug-localhost/

Comment: I already configured this, as I said I can open popups so it means my code runs in localhost.