# Manipulate DOM in EDGE

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-edge

I've been working in some fixes where I'm forced to use a new window to fill part of a form. My approach is to manipulate parent window's DOM as a visual reference of the users selection.

```
window.opener.jQuery('#parent-div');
```

The code above works in Chrome/Firefox. I see, deja vu style, this doesn't work in IE/EDGE. My nightmare once again.

```
Error SCRIPT16386: No such interface supported
jquery.js (5665,4)
```

Edge error links [this useless URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=ES-DO&k=k(VS.WebClient.Help.SCRIPT16386)).
jQuery version [1.11.3](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.js)

I've tried many flavors of selecting parent div. Native and jQuery as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372746/targeting-the-parent-window-using-jquery) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017796/jquery-select-element-in-parent-window) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167455/how-to-access-parent-window-object-using-jquery), and many others without any luck.

Any thoughts? Thank you

Comment: What "doesn't work" means? Is there an error?

Comment: Sorry, I'm so frustrated about this that I forgot the most important part

Comment: Are you [testing this on localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31196295/window-opener-in-microsoft-edge-undefined-when-running-at-localhost)?

Comment: Yes, I've a dev environment running ubuntu. To test in Edge i'm using a windows lan machine. Firefox/chrome examples works with this configuration though

Comment: What's the code at the error line in jquery?

Comment: @AlwinKesler Might be worth following the link I posted and seeing if anything applies...

Comment: @spender I see your point. No, I've a router DNS rule to map to my dev machine's IP, maybe I could check some vagrant configuration following your advise. Let me see where can I start. Thank you