# window.opener is undefined in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, window.opener

I have many popup window.open, used to search for an item, that call back a javascript function from the window.opener to select that item (when the user click on it).

That worked forever in all browsers, but it is not into Edge. I found out that window.opener is "undefined" in Edge only.
It doesn't matter if I try it locally or on my web server, I got the same problem.
And it can't be a security cross-domain thing, my popup are pages from the same web site.

Is there something I missed about Edge? A new requirement the way we use window.open?

For example, if I have an input button that does:

```
window.open('search.aspx','searching');
```

and a javascript function into head part like:

```
function SelectItem(ID)
{
    // insert magic here
    alert('test');
}
```

The following javascript code from search.aspx doesn't work in Edge:

```
window.opener.SelectItem(123);
```

And if I changed it to

```
alert(window.opener);
```

I will see it is undefined.

**Edit 1:**
No, it is not a duplicate of [Window.opener in Microsoft Edge undefined when running at localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31196295/window-opener-in-microsoft-edge-undefined-when-running-at-localhost). I already read this question before asking mine. My problem is happening not only from localhost, but from web server also. It is not a hostname problem.

**Edit 2:**
Easy way to test it, I get the same problem from the w3schools "Try it yourself" example: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open3

**Update (solution):** I had this problem with Edge 38.14393 (Windows 10 version 1607). I just upgrade to Win10 version 1803 (Edge 42.17134) and now it's working fine as expected. Might been a bug in previous Edge version!

Comment: Do these solutions help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31196295/window-opener-in-microsoft-edge-undefined-when-running-at-localhost

Comment: No. I already read this question before asking mine. My problem is happening not only from localhost, but from web server also. It is not a hostname problem.

Comment: I've flag that question to remove the "duplicate" tag. I had the same bug. I had prod1.example.com and prod2.example.com (pointing to public IP), window.opener worked, but on some computer, who had access to dev1.example.com (pointing to local IPs), window.opener was broken on prod1.example.com. I suspect Edge to have flagged *.example.com as "local" because if dev1.example.com, so it broke prod1.example.com.

Comment: I also voted for reopening. I cannot understand the behavior of people voting to close such questions.

Comment: not supported. see: https://caniuse.com/#feat=rel-noopener

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `window.opener` to get a reference to the parent window function. You can assign a function to the newly opened widow like so:

```
function SelectItem(ID)
{
    // insert magic here
    alert('test');
}

var popup = window.open('search.aspx','searching');

if(popup) {
    popup.SelectItem = SelectItem;
}
```

In your popup you can now call `SelectItem`.

Comment: I thought that you got a good idea, but sadly it doesn't work either. I put an `alert(popup);` before your "if" and in IE11, as expected, I get "[object Window]", but in Edge, I get "null".