# Issue with window.open in ie11

Tags: javascript

I am downloading a file using javascript and opening it in new table by using window.open(). it is working fine in chrome and firefox but it in IE11 it  loggedout the user and sends on login page.

my code is as below

```
   AddToolService.onDownloadFileSuccess('GET', 'WebServices/toolService.asmx/downloadFile?listTitle=' + listTitle + '&FileLeafRef=' + FileLeafRef).then(function () {            
    window.open(FileApplicationPath, '_blank');
    console.log(FileApplicationPath);
    document.getElementById('downloadbar').style.display = "none";
});

}
```

Comment: is there any alternative for window.open which also work in IE

Comment: Try `showModalDialog` perhaps

Comment: where are u calling this method in `<a>` ??

Comment: @nitubanasal did u checked this                                                            [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591050/javascript-window-opener-call-parent-function)

Answer (score 1):

`Window.open()` itself opens in new tab, Just remove "_blank". Use the below code.
(I am referring to IE 11)

```
 window.open(url);
```

Comment: can you refer this link and check if any luck  [link](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-download-file-internet)

Comment: this issue is regarding to windoe.open(). I have checked all settings.

Comment: yes i thought u would have.. But making it clear once again ..  it doesnt throw any error also ?  Did u debugged it ?

Comment: it clears the session cookie and sending user to login page.is there any alternative for window.open which also work in IE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88756/discussion-between-nitu-bansal-and-webruster).